# Definition of $\Omega$-group and $\Omega$-composition series

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, terminology, definition, p-groups

What are the definitions of $\Omega$-group and $\Omega$-composition series? No luck searching on the internet..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are probably looking for [groups with operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_with_operators).  If that doesn't sound right, you might try the [$\Omega$-subgroups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_and_agemo_subgroup) from the theory of $p$-groups.